# Getting crash on app startup: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available

Tags: android, crash, production

Production App is getting crash only for one specific user after user goes to specific screen. No other user is facing this issue. I'm not able to figure out the reason why it's crashing.

Please check the logs

```
--------- beginning of main
11-25 21:41:58.760 30319 30369 D CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 160794467; UID 10388; state: ENABLED
11-25 21:41:58.829 30319 30381 I AdrenoGLES-0: QUALCOMM build                   : 223000e821, I12e4aa4c5c
11-25 21:41:58.829 30319 30381 I AdrenoGLES-0: Build Date                       : 01/22/22
11-25 21:41:58.829 30319 30381 I AdrenoGLES-0: OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.32.02.17
11-25 21:41:58.829 30319 30381 I AdrenoGLES-0: Local Branch                     : 
11-25 21:41:58.829 30319 30381 I AdrenoGLES-0: Remote Branch                    : 
11-25 21:41:58.829 30319 30381 I AdrenoGLES-0: Remote Branch                    : 
11-25 21:41:58.829 30319 30381 I AdrenoGLES-0: Reconstruct Branch               : 
11-25 21:41:58.829 30319 30381 I AdrenoGLES-0: Build Config                     : S P 10.0.7 AArch64
11-25 21:41:58.829 30319 30381 I AdrenoGLES-0: Driver Path                      : /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
11-25 21:41:58.835 30319 30381 I AdrenoGLES-0: PFP: 0x016ee190, ME: 0x00000000
11-25 21:41:58.844 30319 30381 D hw-ProcessState: Binder ioctl to enable oneway spam detection failed: Invalid argument
11-25 21:41:58.882 30319 30337 I OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=9223196187727ms; Flags=1, FrameTimelineVsyncId=12349042, IntendedVsync=175849126844642, Vsync=175849126844642, InputEventId=0, HandleInputStart=175849127384546, AnimationStart=175849127385953, PerformTraversalsStart=175849127386421, DrawStart=175849157319185, FrameDeadline=175849142511308, FrameInterval=175849127369546, FrameStartTime=8333333, SyncQueued=175849158084341, SyncStart=175849158178820, IssueDrawCommandsStart=175849158654966, SwapBuffers=175849180857781, FrameCompleted=9223372036854775807, DequeueBufferDuration=9402553, QueueBufferDuration=978854, GpuCompleted=9223372036854775807, SwapBuffersCompleted=175849182870333, DisplayPresentTime=0, 
11-25 21:42:00.340 30319 30337 I OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=9223196186227ms; Flags=0, FrameTimelineVsyncId=12349469, IntendedVsync=175850627098804, Vsync=175850627098804, InputEventId=0, HandleInputStart=175850627646779, AnimationStart=175850627648654, PerformTraversalsStart=175850627801050, DrawStart=175850627864904, FrameDeadline=175850651098803, FrameInterval=175850627642977, FrameStartTime=8333333, SyncQueued=175850627902404, SyncStart=175850627933394, IssueDrawCommandsStart=175850627987300, SwapBuffers=175850631769384, FrameCompleted=9223372036854775807, DequeueBufferDuration=19375, QueueBufferDuration=383333, GpuCompleted=9223372036854775807, SwapBuffersCompleted=175850632785530, DisplayPresentTime=0, 
11-25 21:42:00.390 30319 30319 I PlayCore: UID: [10388]  PID: [30319] AppUpdateService : requestUpdateInfo(com.dry.beat2)
11-25 21:42:00.400 30319 30484 I PlayCore: UID: [10388]  PID: [30319] AppUpdateService : Initiate binding to the service.
11-25 21:42:00.404 30319 30319 I CouchbaseLite/DATABASE: CBL-ANDROID Initialized: CouchbaseLite Android v2.8.6-2 (CE/release, Commit/474b675894@4294f5b7efde Core/2.8.6 (2) at 2021-06-23T01:13:29.983Z) on Java; Android 12; moto g(60)
11-25 21:42:00.408 30319 30319 W CouchbaseLite/DATABASE: Database.log.getFile().getConfig() is now null: logging is disabled.  Log files required for product support are not being generated.
11-25 21:42:00.414 30319 30319 D CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 171228096; UID 10388; state: ENABLED
11-25 21:42:00.426 30319 30485 I AWSKeyValueStore: Detected Android API Level = 31
11-25 21:42:00.426 30319 30485 I AWSKeyValueStore: Creating the AWSKeyValueStore with key for sharedPreferencesForData = com.amazonaws.mobile.client
11-25 21:42:00.427 30319 30485 I AWSKeyValueStore: Detected Android API Level = 31
11-25 21:42:00.427 30319 30485 I AWSKeyValueStore: Creating the AWSKeyValueStore with key for sharedPreferencesForData = com.amazonaws.android.auth
11-25 21:42:00.437 30319 30319 I PlayCore: UID: [10388]  PID: [30319] AppUpdateService : requestUpdateInfo(com.dry.beat)
11-25 21:42:00.437 30319 30319 I PlayCore: UID: [10388]  PID: [30319] AppUpdateService : requestUpdateInfo(com.dry.beat)
11-25 21:42:00.438 30319 30484 I PlayCore: UID: [10388]  PID: [30319] AppUpdateService : Waiting to bind to the service.
11-25 21:42:00.438 30319 30484 I PlayCore: UID: [10388]  PID: [30319] AppUpdateService : Waiting to bind to the service.
11-25 21:42:00.440 30319 30485 W LogFactory: Truncating log tag length as it exceed 23, the limit imposed by Android on certain API Levels
11-25 21:42:00.440 30319 30485 W LogFactory: Truncating log tag length as it exceed 23, the limit imposed by Android on certain API Levels
11-25 21:42:00.442 30319 30485 I AWSKeyValueStore: Detected Android API Level = 31
11-25 21:42:00.442 30319 30485 I AWSKeyValueStore: Creating the AWSKeyValueStore with key for sharedPreferencesForData = com.amazonaws.android.auth
11-25 21:42:00.443 30319 30319 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
--------- beginning of crash
11-25 21:42:00.443 30319 30319 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 21:42:00.443 30319 30319 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.dry.beat, PID: 30319
11-25 21:42:00.443 30319 30319 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Even tried released build with `minifyEnabled false` but that also gives same crash.

If anyone as faced this issue earlier or know how to resolve this or can help getting stack trace. That would be go great help!